# button to copy to clipboard only works on the first div out of several

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Text copied");
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('divid_0')">copy user</button>
<div id="divid_0">abc@gmail.com</div>
<button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('divid_1')">copy user</button>
<div id="divid_1">xyz@gmail.com</div>
```

I used this code from another answer here. It works, BUT only on the first time I run when there's several divs, i.e. whichever 'copy user' button I click, it will copy to clipboard that value, but if I click the other button, the pop up will show 'text copied' but on paste, it will still paste the first value.

Comment: pls combine your javascript and html code snippet together so it will work. btw the css tag isnt needed at all

Comment: Do you want to copy only the text selected by the user at the time of the click? Or do you want to copy text which is below the button, even if that text is not selected? I tried your code and it seems to work fine, it copies the text selected at the time of the click.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to copy the text below the button, and not the selected text, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>

        function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
            const text = document.getElementById(containerid).innerText;
            const listener = function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                ev.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
            };
            document.addEventListener('copy', listener);
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.removeEventListener('copy', listener);
            alert("Text copied");
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('divid_0')">copy user</button>
    <div id="divid_0">abc@gmail.com</div>

    <button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('divid_1')">copy user</button>
    <div id="divid_1">xyz@gmail.com</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I got this code from: https://komsciguy.com/js/a-better-way-to-copy-text-to-clipboard-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that when there is already some text selected that is picked up rather than the newer range's text.

While I have not been able to fully fathom out why this should be, I also noticed that the given code keeps creating ranges. At first I thought of using removeRange to get rid of one before creating another, but apparently this is not implemented in Safari so instead here is an altered snippet where just one range is created and is used each time so we don't keep creating them.

Using just the one range also means that when it comes to reading the selected text it has no chance of picking up the wrong one.

Note: I also noticed that the code in the function which deals with the case where the user has already made some (other) selection seems to depend on a now obsolete function createTextRange which I think was (older versions) IE only so that needs looking at but was not part of this question.

```js
var range = document.createRange();

function CopyToClipboard(containerid, range) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");

  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");

    alert("Text copied");
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('divid_0', range)">copy user</button>
<div id="divid_0">abc@gmail.com</div>

<button id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('divid_1', range)">copy user</button>
<div id="divid_1">xyz@gmail.com</div>
```